# Where is the string table in a Windows DLL?

Tags: c++, winapi, dll, mingw, portable-executable

I have written a routine to dump the symbols and sections from a DLL loaded with `LoadLibrary` but not sure how to decode MinGW DLLs that have section names that are longer than `IMAGE_SIZEOF_SHORT_NAME`

For example, a MinGW DLL outputs the follwing sections if I print them as strings:

```
[".text", ".data", ".rdata", ".pdata", ".xdata", ".bss", ".edata", ".idata",
 ".CRT", ".tls", ".reloc", "/4", "/19", "/31", "/45", "/57", "/70", "/81",
 "/92"]
```

The other sections as `objdump.exe` gets them:

```
.debug_aranges
.debug_info
.debug_abbrev
.debug_line
.debug_frame
.debug_str
.debug_loc
.debug_ranges
```

Which are all longer than `IMAGE_SIZEOF_SHORT_NAME`.  [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680341) explains that:

`For longer names, this member contains a forward slash (/) followed by an ASCII representation of a decimal number that is an offset into the string table.`

So I have the following code:

```
  Char buffer[IMAGE_SIZEOF_SHORT_NAME + 1];
  std::strncpy(buffer, reinterpret_cast<const Char * const>(section_header_ptr[i].Name), IMAGE_SIZEOF_SHORT_NAME);
  buffer[IMAGE_SIZEOF_SHORT_NAME] = '\0';
  const Char * name = buffer;
  if (name[0] == '/') {
    const Long rva = std::strtol(name + 1, NULL, 10);
    if ((LONG_MAX == rva) || (LONG_MIN == rva) || ((0 == rva) && (name[0] != '0'))) {
      static const Char * const failure = "failed to convert offset";
      name = failure;
    }
    // -- How do I get the string table here? and use the offset? --
  }
```

Reading the COFF spec I see that the string table is after the symbol entries so it should be

```
HMODULE handle = LoadLibrary("some_mingw_library.dll");
PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER idh = (PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER)(handle);
PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS inh = (PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS)(((const uint8_t*)(idh)) + idh->e_lfanew)
PIMAGE_FILE_HEADER ifh = &inh->FileHeader;
PIMAGE_SYMBOL is = (PIMAGE_SYMBOL)(((const uint8_t*)(idh)) + ifh->PointerToSymbolTable)
const char * const string_table = &is[ifh->NumberOfSymbols];
```

But I get something that is definitely not the string table.  I can see the string table in my hex editor.  Where is the string table in a portable executable?

Comment: MSDN also says (the link you put)..."Executable images do not use a string table and do not support section names longer than eight characters".

Comment: @mox In Microsoft world, for sure.  MSDN is documentation for Microsoft but the PE and COFF spec is public and is used in UNIX also. You can have a look at the GNU binutils and see that the PE spec has been written via non-`Windows.h` headers.  'Deprecated' by Microsoft means that *they* don't use it anymore, there's no reason why images in the wild cannot have those parts filled out - it's completely supported by the specification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When an executable file is mapped into memory it is not loaded as one contiguous lump.  Sections are scattered about as described in the section headers.

Symbols are not necessarily mapped into memory at all.

`PointerToSymbolTable` is (I think) a file offset, not a memory offset (and, as described above, they are not the same thing).

EXEs and DLLs shouldn't have COFF symbols at all, though this file plainly does.

The answers to most such questions can be found in [PEDUMP](http://www.wheaty.net/downloads.htm).

Comment: PointerToSymbolTable is deprecated and is never used.

Comment: I have the `PEDUMP` source code and that uses the `PointerToSymbolTable` as a file offset (you are correct) as that reads the DLL via mapping the file into virtual memory but I am using the result of `LoadLibrary`.  The sections are scattered around and I can generally find most of the information.  I also think that you are correct that the Symbols are not mapped into memory.

Comment: I guess you'll have to read the symbol table directly from the file.  You've already got the offset.

Answer (score 3):

I know that I'm late here but it seems that the question wasn't fully answered. I came here looking for the same answer myself before finding the solution.

> Where is the string table in a portable executable?

The string table follows immediately after the symbol table. The number of symbols is in the file header information along with the symbol table start address, with each symbol being 18 bytes. A nice easy calculation to get to the string table.

The first 4 bytes are the size of the string table itself ( hence the /4 for the first entry ). Each string follows on from the previous one. Each string is null terminated. Not that this matters as the offsets are in the section name itself so you can look straight at the them.

Answer (score 0):

String tables are not available in Executables (DLL) there are only available in OBJ files. This is why you cannot enumerate these when analysing a PE file. Sections names of PE files are NEVER longer than 8 characters.

Comment: The original poster has a DLL with names longer than 8 characters and objdump correctly decodes them.  "Deprecated" and "never used" are not synonyms.

Comment: Sections names of PE images NEVER have names longer that 8 characters.

Comment: The poster says he has a DLL produced by MinGW that has section names like "/19" that objdump decodes to longer names like ".debug_info".  Do you think he invented these details?

Comment: @mox Seriously, MinGW still uses the old COFF format for the symbols.  Even though the `pecoff_v83.docx` spec says that they are deprecated, that is for the Windows compiler.  I honestly, honestly am not telling you lies - MinGW creates DLLs with section names longer than 8 characters.